# Rails Console requiring Factory Girl fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot, rails-console

I know that FactoryGirl has been deprecated in favor of FactoryBot, but we haven't yet updated our code, so we are still using FactoryGirl. Regardless, requiring FactoryGirl in the Rails Console should work, but it isnt'.

The gem is included properly in my Gemfile

```
group :test, :development do
   ...  
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.9.0'
   ...
end
```

And it appears when I run `bundle`

```
$ bundle | grep factory
Using factory_girl 4.9.0
Using factory_girl_rails 4.9.0
```

But when I require it in the console, it fails.

```
[1] pry(main)> require 'factory_girl_rails'
=> false
[3] pry(main)> require 'factory_girl'
=> false
```

This doesn't seem to happen with any of the other gems in my Gemfile. Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: `require` will return `false` if the library is already loaded in `LOAD_PATH` this is not a failure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When `require` returns `false` then this doesn't mean that an error occured. It means that the feature was already loaded.

From the [documentation of `require`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Kernel.html#method-i-require):

> `require(name)` → `true` or `false`
>
> Loads the given `name`, returning `true` if successful and `false` if the feature is already loaded.

When `require` is not able to load the feature than it will raise a `LoadError`.

Answer (score 2):

It returns `false` because it's already been required and loaded. Try

`FactoryGirl`

to verify the constant exists